# How to stop losing adjustment effect in photoshop when saving image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, texture, flatten

Ok, this problem is driving me round the bend. Basically whenever I try to save my finished drawing on photoshop CS6, the background texture to my drawing darkens considerably. Here are some photos of a zoomed in section for comparison.

Here's the background as I want it to look...

[image]

And here's the background I end up with...

[image]

At first I thought it was something to do with the adjustment effects on layers above the background one cancelling each other out or something, but I have no problem merging or flattening the layers together and achieving the desired look. It’s only when I go to save the image that photoshop robs me of my extra texture! I’ve tried all sorts of solutions from various places online but nothing has worked. I can’t rasterize any of the layers, it doesn’t matter how I merge or flatten them, viewing at 100% zoom doesn’t do anything and saving in other formats doesn’t do anything. What’s especially strange is that other lighter backgrounds don’t have this problem when I save them – there are no changes, but here it happens without fail.

I’m stumped.

Comment: What are your export/save settings?

Comment: Just the default settings - no matte, high quality, baseline standard. I've tried fiddling with all those settings but they have no affect.

Comment: does it happen if you save it as PNG? Are you changing the image size / resolution when exporting? What kind of adjustment layers do you have? What's the color mode in your image?